# Disable the Button from frontEnd

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm trying to disable a button using AngularJS

```
<button
    type="submit"
    ng-disabled="emailConfig.$invalid"
    ng-click="createEmailconfig()"
    class="btn-sm btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light newbtn hvr-glow box-shadow-3 gradientbg"
    name="submit"
    id="submit"
>
    <span class="btn-label"><img src="images/icon/submit.png" style="height: 18px;">
    </span>Submit
</button>
```

If the form is invalid or a specific length isn't met, the button should be disabled. However, it's not working as it's supposed to.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is add [`ng-maxlength`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength) directive to the input fields and the form will be disabled with your current code, checkout this basic working example!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <form action="" name="emailConfig" novalidate>
    <input name="input" ng-model="userType" ng-maxlength="5" required>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="emailConfig.$invalid" ng-click="createEmailconfig()" class="btn-sm btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light newbtn hvr-glow box-shadow-3 gradientbg" name="submit" id="submit">
                                <span class="btn-label"><img src="images/icon/submit.png" style="height: 18px;">
                                </span>Submit
                            </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

some addition to @Naren Murali answer

You have no ng-model and inputs in your example.
You can validate a field using the required attribute and ng-model.

Using ng-model:

```
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
<form action="" name="emailConfig" novalidate>
<label>validation: <input type="text" ng-model="modelName" ng-minlength="4" required></label>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="modelName.$invalid">Button</button> 
</form>
</div>
```

note: Set the novalidate attribute on the form-tag so the default HTML5 validation gets overwritten by Angular in your app.

You can validate a form using the required attribute and the form name.

For your example:

```
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
<form action="" name="emailConfig" novalidate>
<label>validation: <input type="text" ng-model="modelName" ng-minlength="4" required></label>
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="emailConfig.$invalid" ng- 
click="createEmailconfig()" class="yourClass" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```